# How to assign multiple variables from multidimensional array in python

Tags: python

There is a X DataFrame.

```
X=pd.DataFrame({'x':[1,2,3,4,5],'y':[6,7,8,9,10],'z':[11,12,13,14,15]})
```

I want to make a,b,c like this.

```
a=array([1,2,3,4,5])
b=array([6,7,8,9,10])
c=array([11,12,13,14,15])
```

However When i run the code below,

```
a,b,c=np.array(X)
```

I got an error

**ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 3)**

I should change this part **np.array(X)** not **a,b,c** because of package code i am using. But i don't know how to fix it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `pandas.DataFrame.to_numpy()` to convert to `numpy.array`, then transpose it using `numpy.ndarray.T`, and then use `numpy.split`

```
>>> a,b,c = np.split(X.to_numpy().T, [1,2])

>>> a
array([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]], dtype=int64)

>>> b
array([[ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10]], dtype=int64)

>>> c
array([[11, 12, 13, 14, 15]], dtype=int64)
```

If there are guaranteed to be 3 columns only, you can just assign the transposed array

```
>>> a,b,c = X.to_numpy().T
```

If you want `list`, then:

```
>>> a,b,c = X.to_numpy().T.tolist()
```

Comment: Why split? ```a, b, c = X.to_numpy().T``` is enough.

Comment: True, just made sure the code doesn't break if more columns are added. But I should mention it probably. Thanks.